# ¿Se podría considerar "trazable" una traducción correcta de "traceable"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, adjetivos, informática, inglés

Me han preguntado hace poco, en el ámbito de la consultoría informática, cuál sería la forma de traducir al español el término inglés *traceable* aplicado a diseño de software. Mi respuesta automática fue *rastreable*, pero al poco pensé que igual *trazable* podría servir. Consultando el diccionario veo que *trazable* es simplemente "que se puede trazar". Y aquí empieza el juego. El verbo *trazar* tiene la siguiente definición:

> [**trazar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aY9hlGc)
>
> ```
> Del lat. vulg. *tractiāre 'tirar una línea', der. del lat. tractus,
> part. pas. de trahĕre 'traer hacia sí', 'tirar', 'arrastrar'.
> ```
>
> 1. tr. Hacer trazos.
> 2. tr. Delinear o diseñar la traza que se ha de seguir en un edificio u otra obra.
> 3. tr. Discurrir y disponer los medios oportunos para el logro de algo.
> 4. tr. Describir, dibujar, exponer por medio del lenguaje los rasgos característicos de una persona o de un asunto.

No se me ocurre cuál de estas acepciones podría interpretarse como que algo se puede *rastrear*. Sin embargo, el sustantivo *traza* tiene la siguiente acepción:

> **[traza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aY0DN51)**
>
> ```
> De trazar.
> ```
>
> 5. f. Huella, vestigio.

¿Se podría considerar entonces que algo *trazable* es algo de lo que puede seguir su traza (huella)? ¿Creéis que *trazable* podría considerarse pues una traducción válida de *traceable*? ¿Qué palabra se suele usar en el diseño software? ¿Se hablaría de mensajes o eventos rastreables, trazables, *traceables*? ¿O se usa algún otro adjetivo?

Comment: Aunque [*trazabilidad*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aY2C3FX) se usa en el mismo contexto (cf. "traceability"), solo he oído *rastreable* o *localizable* como palabra con el mismo sentido que "traceable" si mismo.

Comment: "traducir al español el término inglés traceable aplicado a diseño de software" ¿por ejemplo? traceable what? una dirección IP se rastrear. Un dibujo se traza: "Para trazar un dibujo a papel o a algún formato como PDF" También hay: http://www.chambers.com.au/glossary/traceability_analysis.php

Comment: @Lambie pues por ejemplo cuando una aplicación se ejecuta y escribe un log se puede revisar la traza de la ejecución y ver por dónde ha pasado el código. ¿Se podría decir que la ejecución del código es trazable?

Comment: Creo que rastrear se usa: https://www.silicon.es/crean-un-software-capaz-de-detectar-el-origen-de-un-virus-informatico-2222436

Comment: Traceable -> Rastreable. Drawable -> Trazable

Answer (score 3):

Al menos en España, "trazabilidad" se emplea con frecuencia en el contexto de la industria alimentaria para referirse a la posibilidad de rastrear un alimento hasta su origen. Eso haría de *trazable* una buena alternativa.

Answer (score 1):

Estabas en lo correcto, "traceable" es "rastreable" y se usa en ese ámbito en la informática.

"Trace" raramente se usa como "trazar" en Inglés.

No estoy de acuerdo con que se utilice "trazable" como sinónimo de "traceable", principalmente por su ambigüedad de significado que puede caer en la misma confusión que "Item" e "Item" y deberían ser tratados como falsos amigos.